# How can I batch decompile multiple .NET assemblies?

Tags: .net, dll, decompiler

How can I batch decompile multiple .NET assemblies at once ?

I tried [Telerik JustDecompiler](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) and [Red Gate .NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/), both of which only decompile .NET assemblies one at a time.

Comment: You can try this plugin [ReflectorFileDisassembler](http://www.denisbauer.com/Home/ReflectorFileDisassembler) which claims to add support for bulk reverse-engineering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Used Red-Gate reflector extension from vs.net and it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

For bulk disassembly, you can use a plugin for Red Gate's *.NET Reflector* by Denis Bauer called [ReflectorFileDisassembler](http://www.denisbauer.com/Home/ReflectorFileDisassembler)

The claim about what this is capable of comes from a quick google search ending up on [this link on Red Gate forums](https://forums.reflector.net/questions/1311/can-net-reflector-be-driven-from-the-command-line.html) in relation to you specific question.

This is a screenshot from his site showing it in action :

[image]

Comment: it decompiles the selected assembly only